# Elements able to find in IRB, but not in webdriver run

Tags: rspec, selenium-webdriver, anchor, overlay, watir-webdriver

I have an anchored overlay in the application, where i need to do 3 actions: input a text, select a checkbox and click on OK. I can locate the elements and walk through these in IRB. But the same code of lines fails at webdriver run. I use rspec. I get the error that   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError:
       Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

HTML looks like:

```
<div id="xwt_widget_form_AnchoredOverlay_0_Popover" class="xwtPopover xwtAnchoredOverlayPopover dijitTooltipDialog xwt_BasePickerPopover disablePointer xwtAnchoredOverlayPopoverBelow dijitTooltipABLeft dijitTooltipBelow" wairole="presentation" widgetid="xwt_widget_form_AnchoredOverlay_0_Popover" style="top: 0px; visibility: visible;">
```

under this, its a table for text box:

```
 <td class="gridxCell " style="width:100px;;min-width:100px;;" aria-grabbed="false">
<div class="quickFilterItem forHeader-ipaddress">
<div id="widget_dijit_form_TextBox_22" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_TextBox_22" style="width: 100px;">
<div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer">
<input id="dijit_form_TextBox_22" class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" tabindex="0" value="">
</div>
```

this is my code:

```
 def overlay_method(text)
      @browser.div(:class => 'xwt_BasePickerButton dijitDownArrowButton').click
      sleep 3
      @browser.div(:class => 'quickFilterItem forHeader-ipaddress').wait_until_present(10)
      @browser.div(:class => 'quickFilterItem forHeader-ipaddress').text_field.set text
      sleep 1
      @browser.span(:class => 'gridxIndirectSelectionCheckBox dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox', :index => 0).click
      sleep 3
      @browser.div(:class => 'xwtAnchoredOverlayPopoverBelow').span(:text => 'OK').wait_until_present(10)
      @browser.div(:class => 'xwtAnchoredOverlayPopoverBelow').span(:text => 'OK').click


  end
```

In the run, looks like the overlay is getting collapsed on trying to enter text or do any action.
Request to give some pointers what I could try. Its confusing that at irb it works but not in the script run. I have tried using focus, hover, send_keys, etc.

update: Figured out that keeping any window on top of the browser run, makes it work.  I kept small terminal window active(focus) on top of the browser run, & I see it working. So now in this kind of behavior how to handle in runs.

Looking for some inputs. Greatly appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Share your code in question please.

Comment: It would help if you could give a sample HTML that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Have updated with more details. Thanks.

Comment: Request for some help here !! SO how do we access elements where another window in focus makes it work.

Comment: It's likely that this is a very subtle problem that will require you to closely examine the page's HTML after every step of your script. Often times this kind of issue is the result of some non-obvious HTML change in an unexpected place you're not even aware is relevant. It's doubtful we can give you any more help than this.

Comment: @Jade, you need to give enough details for us to be able to reproduce the problem. Unfortunately, the HTML added does not appear to be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for this.

The click action which triggered anchored overlay was not really recognized kind of thing by the webdriver. So though the overlay was displayed, webdriver complained that the elements was not visible to interact.
I used .send_keys :enter instead of .click. This made webdriver to understand the overlay had displayed and it easily interacted with the elements on overlay.

Jade